# How does Visual Studio creates WebService Client

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wsdl

We all know that Visual Studio provides a WebReference which is actually generating a proxy class which defines methods representing the actual methods of the exposed webservice XML.

But anyone knows how is it doing it? Which library is used behind that?

Answer (score 0):

SvcUtil.exe

It can be easily accessed via the Visual Studio Command Prompt. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) for utilization.

Personally I've used it quite a bit to set up some test harnesses for enterprise services.

Comment: Well thanks Cameron. I have already created a webservice client. What I am curios here which api is been used in the background. It should be using some SOAP API. Any idea on that?

Comment: I think it is going to depend on how the service endpoint is configured (Net TCP, Basic HTTP, etc). Could even make WCF talk in JSON ;-).

Answer (score 0):

**I found this information by using JetBrains DotPeek.**

I loaded SvcUtil.exe into DotPeek and then looked around.

In answer to what API is it using, there are multiple options of what it can do, but I looked at the `ExportServiceContracts` options, and it appears to use

1. Reflection to pull the types from the assembly.
2. Then it uses the `System.ServiceModel.Description` data type to acquire the ServiceContract information.
3. Then it uses the `System.ServiceModel.Description` name space's `MetadataExporter` to export it to the various files that it creates in the WebReference folder.

Hope this gives you a starting place on how to identify what's going on.  I've found DotPeek to be invaluable when I'm trying to understand the framework and various other tools.  There are, of course, a number of other Dissassembly tools available that could be used.